# ¿Por qué la base de datos me guarda las "ñ" de una forma extraña a través de un javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hace días he tenido problemas con la letra **"ñ"** al momento de guardar y listar, las letra se guardan bien y se muestra bien dentro del `php` y `html`, pero cuando reviso la base datos se muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se hace desde un `javascript` que es una table desplegable según el numero que se digite, osea sin digita 2 el `javascript` despliega 2 filas, etc.

código `javascript`:

```
var contLin = 1;

function agregar() {

    var tr, td;
    var con=0;
while(con<document.getElementById('numer').value){

    tr = document.all.tabla.insertRow();

    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  id='fts_nombre' name='fts_nombre[]'  onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_apellido' name='fts_apellido[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_parentezco' name='fts_parentezco[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_edad' name='fts_edad[]'  onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_escolaridad' name='fts_escolaridad[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_ocupacion' name='fts_ocupacion[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39'>";

    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_vive' name='fts_vive[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39'  >";

    contLin++;
con++;
}

}


function borrarUltima() {
    ultima = document.all.tabla.rows.length - 1;
    document.all.tabla.deleteRow(ultima);
    contLin--;
}

function MAS(){
document.getElementById('pariente').style.display='block';
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que ver que el charset sea de tipo `utf-8`

Comment: Eso quiero hacer , pero no se donde colocarlo dentro de javascript, solo lo he utilizado en php.Dentro de la base de datos esta como utf8_spanish_ci cosa que ha funcionado bien para el resto de las tablas.

Comment: Pero en la base de datos lo tienes definido así?

Comment: utf8_spanish_ci, asi ha funcionado para el resto de las tablas

Comment: Intenta meter tú manualmente desde phpmyadmin una ñ en la tabla, sí te inserta así es el charset, síno, es como le llega al php

Comment: La base de datos deja insertar bien la ñ, pero cuando quiero verla a través del php sale otro símbolo, voy a subir la imagen.

Comment: Hola, aqui hay una explicación detallada sobre el problema que tienes [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/77879)

Comment: En la db solo tienes que cambiar a todos los campos que vas a necesitar por el utf8_spanish_latin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por fin funciono, agregue   var textoUtf8 = utf8_encode(texto);  dentro del javascript ya que este era el que generaba la tabla dentro del php principal que en si tenia mas inputs,todos las repuestas me fueron útiles . Gracias.

```
var contLin = 1;

var textoUtf8 = utf8_encode(texto);


function agregar() {

    var tr, td;
    var con=0;


while(con<document.getElementById('numer').value){

    tr = document.all.tabla.insertRow();

    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  id='fts_nombre' name='fts_nombre[]'  onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_apellido' name='fts_apellido[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_parentezco' name='fts_parentezco[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_edad' name='fts_edad[]'  onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_escolaridad' name='fts_escolaridad[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39' >";
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_ocupacion' name='fts_ocupacion[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39'>";

    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='fts_vive' name='fts_vive[]' onkeypress='return event.charCode != 39'  >";

    contLin++;
con++;
}

}


function borrarUltima() {
    ultima = document.all.tabla.rows.length - 1;
    document.all.tabla.deleteRow(ultima);
    contLin--;
}

function MAS(){
document.getElementById('pariente').style.display='block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisa todas las codificaciones de caracteres como el (encoding en la base de datos, y en todo tu proyecto) verifica que estés usando el UTF-8.

en la parte de la conexion con la base de datos Mysql puedes usar.

`mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');`

Otra opción es que uses `utf8_decode()` y `utf8_encode()`

Nota: recuerda revisar tus codificaciones tanto en el html

Comment: Ufff. Codificar y decodificar todo debería ser la última opción! :)

Comment: utf8_decode() y utf8_encode() ya lo utilice dentro del controlador y no funciona, l a primera opción ya la descarte, y la segunda opción no se donde debe ir dentro de la consulta.

Comment: en parte funciono por que antes nisiquiera mostraba las ñ al listarlas, pero el problema radica en como se muestra en la BD.

Comment: Revisa el encoding en la base de datos (Mysql)

Comment: puedes alterar la tabla "ALTER TABLE `nombre_tabla`
COLLATE=’utf8_general_ci’;

Answer (score 1):

Fijáte en el archivo php que guarda en la BD, poner:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

También abrí el archivo `.php` que guarda con el notepad, y fijate de hacer guardar como y en el charset poner **utf-8** y no ANSI.
Y hace tambien lo que dice @Jozeslond.
Saludos.